# How do you float a span tag outside of a table within a nested div without it being cut off?

Tags: html, css, css-position

What I'm trying to do is literally as the question says, float a span outside of a table, but keeping the span tag within it (for per row reuse purposes).

My understanding was that I needed to use something like `overflow: visible;`, but this does not seem to be having the desired effect (it's currently everywhere in the fiddle below as I was messing with testing it, but I think if it was working, I'd only need it in the inner div (the one using `divStyle2`)?

http://jsfiddle.net/uVQHr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to add `position: relative` to the span's parent `<td>`.

[Here's an updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uVQHr/2/).

The problem is not to do with overflow - you were positioning the `<span>` outside the viewport. If you had inspected the element using your dev tools you would've seen it positioned off the left edge of the screen. You can remove all the `overflow: visible` properties now too.

`position: absolute` positions the element relative to the closest parent element with a `position` attribute that's something other than `static` (default). Your code was positioning the span relative to the `<body>` as no element with a `position` was found.

Comment: Ah, I understand.  I didn't realise it was looking for other position properties to position itself against.  Thanks! :D